# How to handle library dependencies with automake?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, autotools, automake

Let's assume the following project structure composed of one executable in src and two libraries, lib1 and its dependency lib1_dep:

```
  +--src/
  |   |
  |   +--Makefile.am
  |   +--main.c
  |
  +--lib/
  |   |
  |   +--Makefile.am
  |   +--library1.c
  |   +--library1.h
  +--lib_dep/
  |   |
  |   +--Makefile.am
  |   +--library1_dep.c
  |   +--library1_dep.h
  +--Makefile.am
  +--configure.ac
```

The contents of the files are

**configure.ac**

```
# Add libraries dependance
AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS([lib_dep])
AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS([lib])

# Add src files
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile
     lib_dep/Makefile
     lib/Makefile
     src/Makefile
     ])
```

**Makefile.am**

```
SUBDIRS = lib_dep lib src
```

**lib1_dep/Makefile.am**

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = lib_libdep.la
# Dynamic library
lib_libdep_la_SOURCES = library1_dep.c library1_dep.h
lib_libdep_la_LIBADD = 
# Compiler options.
lib_libdep_la_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS)
```

**lib1/Makefile.am**

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = lib_lib.la

# Dynamic library
lib_lib_la_SOURCES = library1.c library1.h
lib_lib_la_LIBADD = $(top_builddir)/lib_dep/lib_libdep.la
# Compiler options.
lib_lib_la_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS) -I$(top_srcdir)/lib_dep/lib_dep.h
```

**src/Makefile.am**

```
bin_PROGRAMS = main

main_SOURCES = main.c

main_LDADD = $(AM_LDADD) $(top_builddir)/lib/lib_lib.la  $(top_builddir)/lib_dep/lib_libdep.la
# Compiler options.
main_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS) -I$(top_srcdir)/lib_dep/lib_dep.h -I$(top_srcdir)/lib/lib_lib.h
```

**Observation**

The build and install work well but I doubt I do it properly. The main program only uses functions defined in lib (not in lib_dep), so it looks strange that I have to also diretly link the main program to lib_dep. I would like your feedbacks on this please.

**Question**

Is there a way to build/compile lib so that I don't have to add the LDAPP and CPPFLAGS related to lib_dep when I build y main program (src/Makefile.am) ?

Thanks

Comment: You should not handle library dependencies at all with automake.  That is not its job.  If you want to bundle libraries with your source code, use convenience libraries.  If you want to rely on external libraries, just have the configure script verify that they are present, but require the user to make them available.  Dependency resolution is a problem for a package management tool (eg dpkg, rpm, yum, or apt) and is *not* something that you should try to solve with automake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The build and install work well but I doubt I do it properly. The main program only uses functions defined in lib (not in lib_dep), so it looks strange that I have to also diretly link the main program to lib_dep. I would like your feedbacks on this please.

It is system-dependent whether indirect shared-library dependencies need to be included in the link.  On Linux, they do.  Compare to the situation with static library dependencies, which absolutely need to be included in the final link, on any system.

However, since you are using `libtool`, in a context where you can rely on its generated .la files to be available, you shouldn't need to provide **explicitly** for linking indirect dependencies.  Libtool can handle that for you.

> Is there a way to build/compile lib so that I don't have to add the LDAPP and CPPFLAGS related to lib_dep when I build y main program (src/Makefile.am) ?

That's actually two separate questions, one for `LDADD` and one for `CPPFLAGS`.

1. The `CPPFLAGS` are relevant only for compilation, not linking.  Roughly speaking, if the main program's sources `#include` any headers from `lib_dep/`, whether directly or indirectly, then it is necessary for its `CPPFLAGS` to contain an `-I` flag for that directory.  Otherwise, not.

   An indirect inclusion would be if `main.c` includes `library1.h` and `library1.h` includes `library1_dep.h`.
2. Since you are using `libtool` to build both libraries, and consistently declaring link dependencies by putting the appropriate libtool archives in the `LIBADD` / `LDADD` variables, you do not need to specify the indirect library dependency in the main program's `LDADD`.  libtool can and will figure out the indirect library dependency and add it to the main program's link if needed, and at the correct location in the link command.

Thus, if the main program has neither a compile-time dependency nor a direct link dependency on `libdep`, then its `Makefile.am` could look like this:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = main

main_SOURCES = main.c

main_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/lib/lib_lib.la
main_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/lib
```

NOTE: it is not wrong to add `$(AM_LDADD)` to `main_LDADD` or to add `$(AM_CPPFLAGS)` to `main_CPPFLAGS`, as in the version of this `Makefile.am` presented in the question, but that is *useful* only if you've actually defined values for those `AM_*` variables.

NOTE2: Your `-I` flags should specify *directories* to search for header files, not the names of specific header files.